# Missing data in raster after using rotate()

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster

I have a netCDF file that I am planning to extract point data from representing the height of pressure for 850hpa annually. However, after using raster::rotate() to correct the x axis a line of missing data appears, as shown below for an example year.
[image]

Can anyone shine some light on this?

The data is available [here](https://climexp.knmi.nl/NCEPNCAR40/z850.nc).

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
data(wrld_simpl) 
r <- raster("z850.nc", band = 5)
r <- rotate(r) ## Corrects extent
plot(r)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = T)
```

Comment: Works for me, windows 7, R 3.2.2, raster_2.5-8, maptools_0.8-41, sp_1.2-3.

Comment: Just updated my raster and sp package and all is now well. Thank you for your help!